# Snowflake SSIS package failure Error Code 370001

Tags: ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We had an unusual failure last night where the SSIS package was loading data into Snowflake Database.
It failed with the error below:

[image]

We did not get any error message in the Snowflake itself  when we checked the history and when we re-ran the package it ran fine.
Could someone please advise on why it has occurred.

Thanks in advance.

Arti

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a transient issue on Cloud Service Layer. To get more detailed information about the internal error, you need to submit a support ticket to Snowflake.